# How can file_get_contents return false without Warning error?

Tags: php

I'm using the PHP function `file_get_contents()` in order to get a string or false. However, whenever this function returns false, I get a warning message.

> Warning: file_get_contents(/mypath/data/data.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in mypath\inc\init.inc.php on line 10

In fact, I'm okay with this function returning false, because this file can be missing, so I don't want this specific warning message to show.

How can I hide this specific warning message? Is there a more proper way to do this?

Here is my code and how I used this function:

```
$csv_file = file_get_contents($csv_path);
```

Comment: Test whether the file exists _first_. Hiding the error is just lazy.

Comment: Prefix file_get_contents with '@' or use file_exists with the file spec. to check before calling file_get_contrents.

Comment: No.  Do not use the stfu operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the file exists before getting its contents:

```
if(file_exists($csv_path)){
  $csv_file = file_get_contents($csv_path);
}
```

Comment: That's a really proper way to do! I was looking for a ``isset()`` equivalent for files. Thank you very much!